# Diversity of a Set & Hypercube Vertices related to Statistical Machine Learning

Tags: elementary-set-theory, machine-learning, dimensional-analysis

I am reading a paper on Statistical Machine Learning and am having a hard time visualizing/understanding some terminology (my background is EE).

The part that I am having a hard time with is this blurb (I will explain what I think I understand after quoting the text):

> Let $Q(z,\alpha),\alpha \epsilon \Lambda $ be a set of indicator functions, that is the functions which only take on values of zero or one.  Consider a sample $z_1 ... z_l$.  Let us characterize the diversity of this set of functions on the given sample by the quantity $N^\Lambda(z_1...z_l)$ that represents the number of different separations of this sample that can be obtained using functions from the given set of indicator functions.
>
> Let us write this in another form.  Consider the set of $l$ dimensional binary vectors $q(\alpha) = \left( Q(z_1,\alpha), Q(z_2, \alpha) ... Q(z_l, \alpha) \right), \alpha \epsilon \Lambda$ that one obtains when $\alpha$ takes various values from $\Lambda$.  Then geometrically speaking, $N^\Lambda(z_1, ... z_l)$  is the number of different vertices of the $l$ dimensional cube that can be obtained on the basis of the sample $z_1 ... z_l$ and the set of functions $Q(z,\alpha), \alpha \epsilon \Lambda$.

I'm trying to understand in English what these two paragraphs mean.  My doubts are:

1. What is meant by "diversity of this set of functions."  In my mind, I'm thinking this intuitively means how different the set of functions $Q(z,\alpha), \alpha \epsilon \Lambda$ are for different values of $\alpha$.  True? False? Why is the diversity $N^\Lambda$ a function of $z_1...z_l$ and not $\alpha$?
2. Is the $N^\Lambda$ a mathematical operator?  I am unaware of that being one, but how to calculate the diversity of the set (referring to paragraph 1) is not explained in the paper.
3. I am able to visualize the set of $l$ dimensional binary vectors (one for each different value of $\alpha$).  This part is pretty easy because $Q(z,\alpha)$ is defined to be an indicator function, i.e. it can only take on values of 0 or 1.  From that though, I am unable to make the leap to *"geometrically speaking, $N^\Lambda(z_1, ... z_l)$  is the number of different vertices of the $l$ dimensional cube that can be obtained on the basis of the sample $z_1 ... z_l$ and the set of functions $Q(z,\alpha), \alpha \epsilon \Lambda$."*

For those that are interested, the paper I am reading is: An Overview of Statistical Learning Theory, by Vladimir Vapnik (IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not just "diversity of this set of functions". It is "diversity on the given sample". That is, $\Lambda$ is fixed, and $N$ depends on $z$. At least that's how I translate it back to Russian.
2. $N^\Lambda$, as far as I know, is introduced in this paper.
3. If I read this correctly, when you apply a particular function from the $Q$ to all samples, it gives you an $l$-dimensional vector. If each end every function results in the same vector, the diversity of the set is pretty low. More vectors you got, more diversified set is. On a given sample of course.

That said, Vapnik is notoriously hard to follow even in Russian.